# JavaScript - set date using locale date string format

Tags: javascript, date, locale

I would like to initialize a date object in JS using local date string format, e.g.:

```
var d = new Date("ma, 14 tammi 2013 10:56:19 +0200"); //invalid Date
```

How is it possible to do so?

Comment: You should have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: You should try this way                                           var d1 = new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00");
var t = d1.toString();
var d2 = new Date(t);
d2.toString();

Comment: Don't use locale date strings to pass time data around, use unix timestamps or UTC dates, and then format for display

Comment: The Date() object only accepts Gregorian Calendar Dates as input. It cannot recognise other calendar dates as inputs